# Show select field with fluid that is filled with `foreign_table` options

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I created an typo3 extension with a frontend plugin where you can create new entries.

One field is a select-field with values from another table. In the TCA it looks like this:

```
'shoeref' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'Shoe Ref Test',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_testcollection_domain_model_testcollection',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'and tx_testcollection_domain_model_testcollection.pid = 96 and tx_testcollection_domain_model_testcollection.sys_language_uid = 0',
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 1,
    ),
),
```

This works in the backend. I can select a record from the table `tx_testcollection_domain_model_testcollection` and also In the frontend I can access this element.

But on the 'New' Page (where you can create a new element) I have no clue how to fill the select field.

I just tried:

```
<f:form.select property="shoeref" />
```

But it says I 'options' are needed. 
Something like this:

```
<f:form.select property="shoeref" options="{0: 'test1', 1: 'test2'}"/>
```

But of course I need the values from the table `tx_testcollection_domain_model_testcollection` in this selectfield.

So how can I get the values of that table (with the same where- condition) into this select field?

---

**Edit I am close:**
I fill a variable in my controller in the newAction:

```
    $collection = $this->objectManager->get('Test\TestCollection\Domain\Repository\TestCollectionRepository');

    $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
    $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
    $querySettings->setStoragePageIds(array(96)); //Looks like he dont care about this and just finds all..

    $collection->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
    $this->view->assign('collecton',$collection->findAll());
```

And in the Template:

```
<f:form.select property="shoeref" options="{collecton}" optionLabelField="name"/>
```

I see the right options, but when I want to save I get:

```
    Exception while property mapping at property path "": PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Test\TestCustomerfeedback\Domain\Model\Customerfeedback::setShoeref() must be an instance of
 Test\TestCustomerfeedback\Domain\Model\Test\TestCollection\Domain\Model\TestCollection
, instance of 
Test\TestCollection\Domain\Model\TestCollection
 given

, called in /home/www-data/typo3_src-7.6.4_dev/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Reflection/ObjectAccess.php on line 209 and defined in /home/www-data/mydomain/typo3conf/ext/test_customerfeedback/Classes/Domain/Model/Customerfeedback.php line 32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type hint for the argument in the methoid `Test\TestCustomerfeedback\Domain\Model\Customerfeedback::setShoeref()` is wrong - it probably looks like this:

```
public function setShoeref(Test\TestCollection\Domain\Model\TestCollection $shoeRef)
{
    // ...
}
```

It should probably look like this:

```
public function setShoeref(\Test\TestCollection\Domain\Model\TestCollection $shoeRef)
{
    // ...
}
```

(additional backslash in the parameter type)

It would be even better to add a `use` statement to the head of you class file, or, in this special case (since both classes `CustomerFeedback` and `TestCollection` are in the same namespace), just use the short `TestCollection` as the type hint:

```
<?php

public function setShoeref(TestCollection $shoeRef)
{
    // ...
}
```

One other thing: Don't fetch your repositories using the object manager, inject them into the class that uses them - You can do so by making the property that should contain them protected, add the needed class as `@var` annotation, and add the annotation `@inject`. Then clear the caches from the install tool, before running that code again.

```
/**
 * @var \Test\TestCollection\Domain\Repository\TestCollectionRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $collectionRepository;
```

Comment: Thanks! The '@inject' is what I was looking for. (I was blind for not seeing it)